# Maven 2 effective dependancies runtime and compile scope

Tags: maven

What happen if I have in effective pom same dependency, but with different scopes: `runtime` and `compile.`?

For example,

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>my_dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>My_dep_subdata</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
....
 <dependency>
        <groupId>my_dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>My_dep_subdata</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Which one will take place?

Comment: are you sure you have both in effective pom ?

Comment: Pretty sure. Pom file have some other pom's included. You can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compile` is available in all classpaths.

`runtime` is available in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

I'd assume you will have the dependency on all classpaths (as in `compile`), but I have no idea why you would do something like that.